# spring integration with activemq

Tags: java, spring, jms, activemq-classic, spring-integration

I'm utilizing spring for about a year and everything was pretty obvious and simple until I faced spring integration. Ashamed, I can't create Outbound Gateway to send message to remote JMS (ActiveMQ) channel. Before integration I just used JmsTemplates and @JmsListeners directly, there were no problems at all.

1. What's the difference between `request-destination` and `request-channel`?
2. Here are my configs:

   ```
       @Configuration
       @EnableJms
       public class JmsConfig {
        ...


           @Value("${activemq.url}")
           private String brokerUrl;


           @Bean
           public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate() {
               JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate(queueConnectionFactory());
               jmsTemplate.setDefaultDestinationName(bookingChannelName);
               return jmsTemplate;
           }
           /*
           @Bean(name = "bookingChannel")
           public Queue activeMQQueue() {
               return new ActiveMQQueue(bookingChannelName);
           }
           */            


           @Bean
           public JmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory() {
               SimpleJmsListenerContainerFactory listenerFactory = new SimpleJmsListenerContainerFactory();
               listenerFactory.setConnectionFactory(queueConnectionFactory());
               return listenerFactory;
           }
           ...
   ```

   }

   and an xml one, where all I've got in root `beans` element is:

   ```
   <jms:outbound-gateway request-destination-name="reqDestination" request-channel="bookingChannel" />
   ```

   Then, there is a gateway code:

   ```
   @MessagingGateway
   public interface BookingGateway<T> {

       @Gateway
       void bookTicket(T ticket);
   }
   ```

   And finally, here is how I use a gateway:

   ```
   @Component
   public class BookingGatewayImpl<T> {


       @Autowired
       private BookingGateway bookingGateway;

       public <U> void bookTicket(T ticket, BiConsumer<T, U> onStatusReceived) {
           bookingGateway.bookTicket(ticket); // second param is not utilized yet
       }
   }
   ```

And when ticket is about to be booked, I get:

```
send is not supported, because no request channel has been configured
```

Also, I am not able to uncomment ActiveMQQueue bean from the first listing because spring says it is not compatible with MessageChannel:

```
Bean named 'bookingChannel' must be of type [org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel], but was actually of type [org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue]
```

Why oh why should the destination be of `MessageChannel` type? What exactly am I doing wrong and how to get this ticket message to be sent?

Answer (score 1):

`bookingChannel` is a `MessageChannel` between your `MessagingGateway` and the jms gateway. The destination is the AMQP Queue.

Use

```
@Gateway(requestChannel="bookingChannel")

@Bean(name = "bookingDestination")
public Queue activeMQQueue() {
    return new ActiveMQQueue(bookingChannelName);
}

@Bean(name = "bookingChannel")
public MessageChannel bookingChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}

<jms:outbound-gateway request-destination-name="bookingDestination" request-channel="bookingChannel" />
```

Comment: `<jms:outbound-gateway request-destination-name="bookingDestination" request-channel="bookingChannel" />`

 - 
`request-destination` instead I guess. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, came up with following configuration. Almost understood the way it's working now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
       xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms"
       xmlns:id="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms/spring-integration-jms.xsd">

    <bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
        <property name="brokerURL" value="nio://127.0.0.1:61616"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="requestQueue" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue">
        <constructor-arg value="bookingChannel"/>
    </bean>

    <id:channel id="requestChannel"/>

    <bean id="channelInterceptor" class="c.e.mentoring.integration.gateway.RequestChannelInterceptor"/>
    <jms:outbound-channel-adapter channel="requestChannel" destination="requestQueue"/>
    <int:channel-interceptor ref="channelInterceptor"/>
</beans>
```